# Elegant solution for streaming media from home server

Tags: linux, streaming, video-streaming

I recently moved (~65mi). I have all my files on my Linux Server at home. I want to find a way to have 2 Ubuntu Workstations (at my office/apartment) and Laptop to all be able to stream my media from my home server. (The server get about 600kbps upstream).

Accessing the files I found OpenVPN and NFS to work great - however streaming my videos hasn't been so good - its extremely choppy and unwatchable. I realize there is no perfect solution, but is there anything that could be setup to buffer/prefetch/compress videos making them tolerable to watch?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a streaming server such as Darwin. 
http://dss.macosforge.org/

Comment: I wasn't aware of this specifically but I wanted to avoid a dedicated streaming server solution - I was looking for a more seamless, like gstreamer.

Answer (score 0):

PLEX: http://www.plexapp.com/

SubSonic: http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp

Both are easy to setup and will stream video, music, etc over the internet to your phone or web browser. With PLEX you can also stream to a Roku as well.

The PLEX is best for intranet media server and Subsonic is great to have facing outside as it has authentication to log in.